# Getting Error: HTTP status code: 403 when trying to post to facebook friends wall

Tags: cocoa-touch, facebook-graph-api

Here's my code:

```
NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               appId, @"app_id",
                               link, @"link",
                               picture, @"picture",
                               NSLocalizedString(@"_findFriends_inviteFriend_title", @""), @"name",
                               NSLocalizedString(@"_findFriends_inviteFriend_description", @""), @"description",
                               NSLocalizedString(@"_findFriends_inviteFriend_message", @""),  @"message",
                               nil];
NSString * graphPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/feed", friendId];

PF_FBRequest * request = [[PF_FBRequest alloc] initWithSession:[PFFacebookUtils session] graphPath:graphPath parameters:params HTTPMethod:@"POST"];

PF_FBRequestConnection *newConnection = [[PF_FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

[newConnection addRequest:request completionHandler:nil];

[newConnection start];
```

Before doing that I check if user's got the permissions:

```
if ([PF_FBSession.activeSession.permissions indexOfObject:@"publish_stream"] == NSNotFound)
{
    [PFFacebookUtils reauthorizeUser:[PFUser currentUser]
              withPublishPermissions:@[@"publish_stream"]
                            audience:PF_FBSessionDefaultAudienceFriends
                               block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
                                   if (succeeded)
                                   {
                                       [self postOnWall:indexPath];
                                   }
                                   else{
                                       //
                                   }
                               }];
    return;
}

[self postOnWall:indexPath];
```

Problem is I get **Error: HTTP status code: 403**

Comment: possible duplicate of [Posting to friends' wall with Graph API via 'feed' connection failing since Feb 6th 2013](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/14792062/posting-to-friends-wall-with-graph-api-via-feed-connection-failing-since-feb)

Comment: you need to get the "publish_actions" extended permissions to enables your app to post content, comments, and likes to a user's stream and to the streams of the user's friends.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/

Comment: @Igy you're right, it works differently after Feb 6th